# How do I detect if a visitor is on a mobile browser with bottle.py?

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I'm a beginner at bottle.py, and I'm trying to make a website where the HTML is changed based on if the visitor is on a PC or mobile device. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest searching for relevant web pages on Google, doing some reading, and then trying to implement what you need. If you have specific questions after that, then we can help you get past those specific issues (please include your code at that point).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to just send every client the same HTML, then have some css/js framework (like Bootstrap for example) format and display it based on the display size of the client.

The only hint you can get is the User-Agent from the client, which the user of course can change. So don't rely on the User-Agent. If you still want to see the User-Agent, just import the `request` object from bottle and then access the headers. See example below:

```
from bottle import route, run, request

@route('/')
def hello():
    print(request.headers['User-Agent'])
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```